# Create a for loop within a MySQL query

Tags: mysql, node.js

My query is:

```
connection.query("SELECT * FROM posts WHERE someId = 2", (err, rows) => {

    allIds = [];

            for(var i = 1; i <= rows.length; i++){
                allIds.push(rows.id_post)
            }

             res.send("The IDs : " + allIds )
});
```

`rows.length = 5`, I'm getting the response: `The IDs : , , , , ,`. There is no data. I need all the IDs listed. Later want to run another query with those Ids, maybe in the same query but for now why aren't the IDs showing? What am I missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems like 'rows.id_post' is undefined. Are you sure there is a property named 'id_post'? Is rows a json or an array? If it's an array you need:

```
for(var i = 0; i < rows.length; i++){
        allIds.push(rows[i].id_post)
    }
```

This should answer your question.

Comment: Thanks. So what's causing `i<=rows.length` to fail and `<` to pass? Did that or `i=0` is resolving this?

Comment: arrays are 0 indexed. so the object array[array.lenght] doesn't exist.

Comment: Can you help me with https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46302496/recursive-query-issue-with-mysql please. Same query extended.

Answer (score 0):

```
for(var i = 1; i <= rows.length; i++){
            allIds.push(rows.id_post)
        }
```

You're not referencing the index of the rows results... I'm not familiar with the Node.JS syntax but I would think you need to reference the i row to get the value to push...

Comment: You mean `allIds.push(rows[i].id_post)`? I tried that and get error : `TypeError: Cannot read property 'id_comment' of undefined`

Comment: try this:
    connection.query("SELECT * FROM posts WHERE someId = 2", function selectAll(err, rows, fields) {